# Is there a fix or work around for jqGrid executing script tags when performing a save of an inline-edit

Tags: jqgrid

I have found a comment by zbacsi on jqgrids site under inline editing.
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#how_is_the_data_organized

"zbacsi, 2010/08/02 20:23
There is an escaping bug with special characters. Try insert alert('hello') into a field. It should be displayed as common text, but its executed..."

I was able to reproduce this issue, on my own grid setup, using the below versions of jqGrid and jQuery.

jqGrid version - > 4.4.4, jQuery version - > 1.7.1.

This can also be reproduced on the inline editing demo pages for jqGrid, located at:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Once there navigate to:

Functionality -> Formatter Actions and begin editing a row.

Inside of the column labeled 'Notes' insert the value: `<script>alert('hi')</script>`

Hit enter or click the 'Save' icon.

The alert('hi') gets executed rather than 'Notes' containing `<script>alert('hi')</script>`

Any additional information would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. You can fix the problem by usage option

```js
autoencode: true
```

which I personally strictly recommend you to use the option *in all grids*.

jqGrid have many options. I personally find default values of some options (see values in "Default" column on [the page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) documentation) not optimal. One from such options is `autoencode` which default value is `false`. It means that all data used to fill the grid cells will be interpreted as *HTML code fragments*. Scripts are the only problem which one have, but inserting the text like `a>b`, `</tr>` or `<--` could really break the page.

jqGrid allow to overwrite the default by extending `$.jgrid.defaults`. So I include on every HTML page JS file with my own default preferences. In the file there are lines like

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    autoencode: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: "auto"
    datatype: "json",
    loadui: 'block',
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg, that does fix the issue with jqGrid executing script tags.